# Python Computer Vision Contours: Too many values to unpack?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I was taking source code from pyimagesearch.com to make a mobile document scanner and tried to test out the code. The edge detection part works but whenever I arrive at the part where it tries to find contours of an image, the program outputs an error saying that there are too many values to unpack, despite the programming working on the author's side.

What's the problem and how do I fix it?

Blog Post about the source code:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/?__vid=c35c22a06af30132982122000b2a88d7

Youtube video about the program:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRer1GC2298

Terminal Command in Ubuntu

```
python scan.py --image images/page.jpg
```

Result:

```
STEP 1: Edge Detection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scan.py", line 40, in <module>
    (cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Code:

```
# USAGE
# python scan.py --image images/page.jpg 

# import the necessary packages
from pyimagesearch.transform import four_point_transform
from pyimagesearch import imutils
from skimage.filter import threshold_adaptive
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True,
        help = "Path to the image to be scanned")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image and compute the ratio of the old height
# to the new height, clone it, and resize it
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
ratio = image.shape[0] / 500.0
orig = image.copy()
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 500)

# convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and find edges
# in the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 200)

# show the original image and the edge detected image
print "STEP 1: Edge Detection"
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imshow("Edged", edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# find the contours in the edged image, kee
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, ping only the
# largest ones, and initialize the screen contourcv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]

# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
        # approximate the contour
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

        # if our approximated contour has four points, then we
        # can assume that we have found our screen
        if len(approx) == 4:
                screenCnt = approx
                break

# show the contour (outline) of the piece of paper
print "STEP 2: Find contours of paper"
cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Outline", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# apply the four point transform to obtain a top-down
# view of the original image
warped = four_point_transform(orig, screenCnt.reshape(4, 2) * ratio)

# convert the warped image to grayscale, then threshold it
# to give it that 'black and white' paper effect
warped = cv2.cvtColor(warped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
warped = threshold_adaptive(warped, 250, offset = 10)
warped = warped.astype("uint8") * 255

# show the original and scanned images
print "STEP 3: Apply perspective transform"
cv2.imshow("Original", imutils.resize(orig, height = 650))
cv2.imshow("Scanned", imutils.resize(warped, height = 650))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: what will this line return? `image = imutils.resize(image, height = 500)`? will it change how `image` will be? Because omitting this line, the code runs fine in my laptop

Comment: It resizes the image to a height of 500. When I omitted it, the un-resized images popped out as extremely large images (it covered the screen).

Surprisingly, even when I do that, I still get the same error: File "scan.py", line 40, in <module>
    (cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Are you saying that with that code, it did not work on your end either, but once you removed it, it suddenly worked?

Comment: I haven't got `pyimagesearch` installed to start with. So I can only remove those lines, and when I run the code there's no exception raised. Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: This was the entire error output for running the script. What happens is that it shows me two images that popped up (one image and one image with edge detection) and print out "Step 1: Edge Detection". Then after you close the two images to move on, the script continues and gives me an error involving too many values to unpack.

STEP 1: Edge Detection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scan.py", line 40, in <module>
    (cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: This is a blog post explaining how the code is suppose to work along with a Youtube video of what the program looks like when it's actually working: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/?__vid=c35c22a06af30132982122000b2a88d7

Comment: can you comment out the line with problem and just `print edged.copy()` and see what image arrays it returns?

Comment: This is what it prints out:  STEP 1: Edge Detection
[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scan.py", line 42, in <module>
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]
NameError: name 'cnts' is not defined

Comment: Your `edged.copy()` looks fine. I'm afraid I can't really help much further why it failed on your end. Is your `cv2` installed properly?

Comment: I would like to at least understand the problem first. Can you explain to me what it means for a contour to have too many values to unpack?

Comment: the `ValueError: too many values to unpack` means your line ` (cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` where `cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` is producing less returns than `(cnts, _)` <- 2 expected returns (in this case only 1 return).

Comment: However `cv2.findContours()` should be like this => `cv2.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) → contours, hierarchy` having 2 returns. So somewhere down the lines doesn't make sense, perhaps the arguments you're passing: **edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE**, and I suspected **edged.copy()** is not producing what it should be... however it is indeed valid.

Comment: It's okay, I figured out the problem. Apparently, I am using a different version of OpenCV and I was using the incorrect syntax. I managed to get it to work.

Comment: ha, glad you've solved this! You may post your answer and let this SO close

Comment: Sure! By changing the line into "_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)" the program managed to work.

Comment: what version of cv2 you have? I was thinking to ask you if you have it installed properly. Anyway, you should post and accept your own answer so others having similar problem may find the relevant solution

Comment: It turns out that I downloaded '3.0.0-beta'. So just now, I found out I downloaded a beta version. Would it be better to change to version 2.4.9. ? I download the cv2 package from GitHub and it gave me this version

Comment: This is entirely up to you, depending the importance on the application you write, if it's business critical, don't use beta as it's not matured or tested enough for use in production. However in your case, I think it's more about hobby thing so it's OK to try out 3.0 beta. Just that you may come across similar problems like you had wouldn't be answered due to the new API changes.

Answer (score 6):

This is the answer at least works for me. The function return 3 values so:

```
_,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(_,cnts,hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV 3.0.0 (beta) they have added a return value. This works:

```
derp,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

I have no idea what `derp` is and it can be ignored.

Comment: Please [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your answer to improve its readability.